# XMLHTTPRequest.send() in not working firefox

Tags: javascript

The following piece of js code is not working only in firefox but works fine in chrome and IE. Can anyone please help.

I am trying to submit two forms with a single click of a button

```
function abc(url){
var form = document.getElementById("sample");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("actionCode=2");

var form1 = document.getElementById("sample1");
form1.submit();
}
```

What's strange is that on placing place a debugger using firebug at line xhr.send() it works, as soon as I remove the debugger from firebug, xhr.send does not execute.

Any suggestions are really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly does not work? Sending request or submitting form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is async request, you need to check status of the request

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
 if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
   var form1 = document.getElementById("sample1");
   form1.submit();
 }
}
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type",  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("actionCode=2");

or this may help

xhr.open("POST", url, false); - it will make the request synchronous. 
Then you will not required to move submit or listen to events
```

And additional way to submit form data
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Why is it necessary to listen for a *response* to make the *request* work?

Comment: @Felix Kling It is unnecessary but you are submitting form exactly after sending request, this request is async it means that function will not stacked on xhr.send until response and will go forward to submit, that will submit form and may cut your request. If you will move submit to the place of alert(xhr.responseText); it will submit form after receiving response

Comment: @Felix Kling or you can do your request sync by replacing true with false xhr.open(type, url, false);